Why is this matrix square root in the closed-form expression of the Wasserstein-2 distance of two Gaussians defined?
The Wasserstein-2 (Frechet) distance of two multivariate Gaussians $P \sim N(\mu_1, \Sigma_1), Q \sim N(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$ is computed as
$\| \mu_1-\mu_2\|_{2}^{2}+\mathop {\mathrm {tr} } {\bigl (}\Sigma_{1}+\Sigma_{2}-2{\bigl (}\Sigma_{2}^{1/2}\Sigma_{1}\Sigma_{2}^{1/2}{\bigr )}^{1/2}{\bigr )}$.
In some sources (e.g. here), it is written as
$\| \mu_1-\mu_2\|_{2}^{2}+\mathop {\mathrm {tr} } {\bigl (}\Sigma_{1}+\Sigma_{2}-2{\bigl (}\Sigma_{1}\Sigma_{2}{\bigr )}^{1/2}{\bigr )}$.
However, $\Sigma_1\Sigma_2$ is not necessarily positive semi-definite, so what justifies the notation $(\Sigma_1\Sigma_2)^{1/2}$ which might not be uniquely determined?
